# df does not show full disk space available for lvm root

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, lvm

I researched this problem, but have not found exact questions.
I installed ubuntu server on ~512G SSD, so I have 474G mounted at root:
[image]

Checking free space with df -H returns only 106G as a size of root filesystem:
[image]

Is it just a glitch and should I just move forward with this ?

Comment: `lsblk` is telling you the size of the *block device* (in this case, an LVM logical volume), whereas `df` is telling you the size of the *filesystem* that was created on that block device

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.